# Magento SEO Store Views

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, store-view, seo

I have trouble with SEO optimization on Magento.
I have one website, one store and 2 store views: one for uk and one for fr.

I am trying to improve the SEO but for the moment on google.fr for instance the description and title that are returned is the english version while i was expecting the french version.

I have configured my store to have the right description depending on the store view (in **configuration -> Design -> HTML Head**). Though it looks like google does not pick this.

I am not sure how i should configure the information for the

> Default configuration, the default website, the Store and the Store Views

Or maybe there are some other elements to configure

Thanks a lot

Comment: GeoIP might help.

Comment: Are you using 2 different domain names or same domain with store codes added in the url?

Comment: @AlainBanutz: use one single domain and 2 store views (on a single store). The Store code are not added to the URL for the moment. So i have issue with duplicate content too.

Comment: @Prateek: We already have this but the issue is that google only referenced the english version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must separate the 2 versions of the website per language by adding store codes to url's according to language or in sepparate subdomains of the same main domain name (the one that you are using now).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I heard that adding the store code to url might cause issues for Paypal or payment systems? Also could it cause any other problems that i should anticipate before implementing it? thanks

Comment: As long as you have the same url's set in your Paypal account it shouldn't be a problem. Same for any other third party application or extension.

Comment: Thanks @AlainBanutz. I have a last question: is it better to use the option "Add store code to URL" in magento configuration, or do you recommend using a sub-directories for each language (fr and en) copy the index.php and htaccess and then change the Base URL with /fr or /en?

Comment: Like in most of the cases for a Magento multistore enviroment adding the store code to url via Magento backend is the best solution in your case also.